# Pandas dataframe hide index functionality?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to hide the index when displaying pandas DataFrames, so that only the column names appear at the top of the table?

This would need to work for both the html representation in ipython notebook and `to_latex()` function (which I'm using with `nbconvert`).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Set `index=False`

For ipython notebook:

```
print df.to_string(index=False)
```

For to_latex:

```
df.to_latex(index=False)
```

Comment: This shows the output as plain text. In Jupyter I'm losing the nice table layout. Is there a way to do this while keeping the nice table?

Comment: @WillemvanDoesburg:
`from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(df.to_html(index=False))`

Comment: Not asked in the questions, but I came here for the DataFrame.to_csv function. For future reference, it also accept this.

Comment: I don't see how this fully answers the question. There should be _one_ command that displays the df correctly in the nb (as html), and while exporting to latex/pdf it will render as table. (Both without index of course.) The HTML() method by @WillemvanDoesburg fix the HTML parts but breaks latex.

Comment: Specifically HTML() returns "<IPython.core.display.HTML object>" with nbconvert -to pdf.

Answer (score 48):

As has been pointed out by @waitingkuo, index=False is what you need. If you want to keep the nice table layout within your ipython notebook, you can use:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML(df.to_html(index=False)))
```

Comment: This only works for HTML, the OP requests is to work with both HTML and Latex.

Comment: Is this efficient if you render a notebook with 20 different df's to html? You have to insert this line for each data-frame?

Answer (score 48):

Starting from v. 0.17.1 it is possible to hide the index via [styling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html), see [hiding the index or colums](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Hiding-the-Index-or-Columns): if `df` is your Data Frame just do

```py
df.style.hide(axis="index")
```

```py
# Legacy Pandas versions
df.style.hide_index()
```

Please note that styling works only in the notebook, and not within the LaTeX conversion.

Comment: The `.style` method breaks conversion to latex/pdf, rendering only `<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler at 0x......>`.

Comment: @MartinThøgersen thx for pointing this out. I was googling for an option to hide the index in the notebook and found this discussion. After some other research I learned about styling and I thought useful to add my answer in this discussion. Unfortunately I didn't pay attention to the OP request for LaTeX also.

Comment: Edited the answer to update the API to modern Pandas versions.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```py
df.style.hide(axis="index")
```

Else you will see:

```bash
FutureWarning: this method is deprecated in favour of `Styler.hide(axis="index")`
  df.loc[df.index,['name','depth']].style.hide_index()
```

See [DEPR REF: hide(axis=..) replaces hide_index and hide_columns #43771](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/43771)

Answer (score 5):

I added the following cell to my notebook which works fine in Jupyter 4.0.2.

Note: It removes the first column of 'any' table even when there is no index.

```
# Execute this cell to remove the first column of dataframe tables (to remove index column)
from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML("""
<style>
    table.dataframe thead th:first-child {
        display: none;
    }
    table.dataframe tbody th {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
""")
```

Answer (score 4):

The style.hide_index is depreciated since Pandas 1.4. For those wanting to know how to hide the index in Notebooks with latest pandas use:

```py
df.style.hide(axis='index')
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `index=False`.

E.g:

```
DataFrame.to_csv("filename", index=False)
```

This will work.

Answer (score 1):

You just try this code, might help you.

```
dataframe.style.hide_index()
```