# Is there anyway to remove index number in python when using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is just a simple code that can take out some dataframes by using input dates.
It works right, but my issues has suddenly appeared once more.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

plt.rc('font', family = 'Malgun Gothic')
df = pd.read_csv('seoul.csv', encoding = 'cp949', index_col=False)
df.style.hide_index()
del df['지점']

a = input("날짜 입력 yyyy-mm-dd: ")
b = input("날짜 입력 yyyy-mm-dd: ")

df['날짜'] = pd.to_datetime(df['날짜'])
mask = (df['날짜']>=a) & (df['날짜']<=b)
df.loc[mask]
```

And this is the result.

[image: The result]

How can I remove these numbers?(the row that I point out with a red box)

oh edit: change `index_col=0` is not work since some of rows are in a different level.

Comment: Try `df.to_csv(filename, index=False)`

Comment: you can use  `d.reset_index(drop=True)` to reset it, but you can't remove it, if you remove the index how you access ?

Comment: you have to call the `Styler.hide_index` each time you want  to hide your index

Comment: huh yeah that is true lol

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas dataframe hide index functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256013/pandas-dataframe-hide-index-functionality)

Answer (score 1):

The index is the way the rows are identified. You can't remove it.
You can only reset it, if you make some selection and want to reindex your dataframe.

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

If the argument `drop` were set to `False`, the indexes would come in an additional column named `index`.

Comment: this changes my index to 0, it does not completely gets ommited out of the result

Comment: @Gel As they said, *"You can't remove it. You can only reset it"*

Answer (score -2):

> Try `df.to_csv(filename, index=False)`

– [tbhaxor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10362396/tbhaxor) [Jan 14, 2020 at 9:27](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59730740/#comment105610864_59730740)

Comment: This is a copy-paste of a comment from another user on the question, which doesn't address the question. Incidentally, the question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256013 (which has an accepted, correct, answer)