Group by and transform the value each group with its median
I have a Pandas dataframe with data like this:
Name,Year,Value
----------------
Wendys,2021,6915
Wendys,2021,6916
Wendys,2022,6943
Wendys,2022,7016
Wendys,2022,7026
Wendys,2022,7028
Wendys,2023,7055
Wendys,2023,7128
Wendys,2023,7129
Wendys,2023,7138
Wendys,2023,7140
Wendys,2024,7166
White Castle,1950,88
White Castle,1950,90
White Castle,1951,91
White Castle,1951,92
White Castle,1951,93

I want to transform it to this:
Name,Year,Value
----------------
Wendys,2021,6915.5
Wendys,2022,6979.5
Wendys,2023,7129
Wendys,2024,7166
White Castle,1950,89
White Castle,1951,92

Note above:

6915.5 is median(6915,6916)
7129 is median(7055,7128,7129,7138,7140)


u can use df.groupby(["Name", "Year"])["Value"].median(). Full example:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Name": ["Wendys", "Wendys", "Wendys", "Wendys", "Wendys", "Wendys", "Wendys", "Wendys", "Wendys", "Wendys", "Wendys", 
             "Wendys", "White Castle", "White Castle", "White Castle", "White Castle", "White Castle"],
    "Year": [2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2024, 1950, 1950, 1951, 1951, 1951],
    "Value": [6915, 6916, 6943, 7016, 7026, 7028, 7055, 7128, 7129, 7138, 7140, 7166, 88, 90, 91, 92, 93]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.groupby(["Name", "Year"])["Value"].median()

result will be:
Name          Year
Wendys        2021    6915.5
              2022    7021.0
              2023    7129.0
              2024    7166.0
White Castle  1950      89.0
              1951      92.0

or:
df.groupby(["Name", "Year"], as_index=False)["Value"].median()

and result will be:
Name  Year   Value
0        Wendys  2021  6915.5
1        Wendys  2022  7021.0
2        Wendys  2023  7129.0
3        Wendys  2024  7166.0
4  White Castle  1950    89.0
5  White Castle  1951    92.0


This is even better if you throw a reset_index on the end.

@AndrewYim Yes I dont want the numbering introduced. end or beginning ?

@ishandutta2007 In the first solution, change df.groupby(["Name", "Year"])["Value"].median() to df.groupby(["Name", "Year"]).median().reset_index()

@AndrewYim doesnt work. Still has the numberings.

@ishandutta2007 You can't really drop the numberings - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59731668

@AndrewYim As a work around I am doing this df.to_csv("temp.csv", index=False) and then reopening it. But this isn't the best solution, or is it ? –

@ishandutta2007 That looks fine. I don't know if another solution exists; you might just have to remove the index every time you export the dataframe.
