# Removing the left index Column

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, indexing

How would I be able to remove the left side of the column in the display and get Expected Output below?

```
import pandas as pd 

d = {'indexes': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
d = df.reset_index(drop=True)
display(d)
```

Output:

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean like [Pandas dataframe hide index functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21256013/15497888)

Comment: Question's unclear. If the goal is just to display w/out index: `print(df.to_string(index=False))`.

Comment: `df = df.set_index('indexes')`?

Answer (score 0):

I see that in your question, you wanted a cosmetic touch up on the display.  To do that, you can set all the index to empty string as below.  You get exactly the output you wanted in the question.

```
import pandas as pd 

d = {'indexes': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
d = df.copy(deep=True)
d.index = ([','.join('') for i in range(len(d))])
display(d)
```

[image]

Note:

1. Whether you want to do a deepcopy is up to you.  I did cause just doing a `d = df`, you will see it also change the index of df.
2. Alternatively, you can just use df, set the index to '' and then reset_set it after.