Pretty printing Python Pandas Dataframe without header nor Index
I'm trying to pretty print a Pandas dataframe without Header nor index, without success
This pretty prints but prints also header and index
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display

data=pd.DataFrame(same_data)
display(data)



This removes index (not header) but does not pretty prints
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display, Markdown

data=pd.DataFrame(same_data)
display(Markdown(data.to_markdown(index=False)))


What am I doing wrong?

This is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35693013/5901382. In addition to index=False, you also need to pass in header=False

For those coming here with the same problem, that's how I finally solved it
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display, HTML

display(HTML(
    ref_signs_table.to_html(
        index=False, 
        header=False, 
        notebook=True
    ).replace('<td>', '<td align="right">')
))


